# Sharepoint: Why do I not get the option to create new Survey, Discussion, Wiki etc?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, survey

I have created a new web application (port 44455) to host all the discussions, surveys and wikis that we will want. I then created a new site collection (which uses the publishing template) and then tried to create a survey (AllSiteContent --> Create --> Tracking --> Survey) but the only option presented was 'Tasks'.

Why is this? On the main web application (port80), all the options were available. Did I forget somthing? The wrong site template?

Paul

[I know this isn't programming exactly but it isn't server-related either. I just know there are some Sharepoint experts here...]

Comment: I wonder why they create sharepointoverflow, as it is same as stackoverflow + sharepoint tag.
We could have bunch of
aspnetoverflow
javaoverflow
coverflow
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate the "Team Collaboration Lists" under Site Actions -> Modify All Site Settings -> Site Features (not site collection features)

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to

> Site Actions -> Site Settings ->
>   Modify all Settings -> Site Colection Features

and see if the following are activated.

1. Office SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features
2. Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure

Comment: Thanks for the hint but these items are all activated.

Comment: You were almost right! The path is:
Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Modify all Settings -> SiteFeatures

Now it works!